# How can I move to the Jakarta namespace while using Amazon MQ?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis, amazon-mq

I'm trying to migrate a codebase from Java 11 to 17, but I'm stuck with the ActiveMQ client artifact which is bound to the `javax` package which is removed from the JDK in later versions.

The system connects to a Amazon MQ broker (running ActiveMQ 5) using the OpenWire protocol. Thinking I hit the jackpot, I tried replacing the ActiveMQ client with the Apache Artemis client which also supports JMS but it doesn't seem to be able to connect the Amazon MQ broker.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null
```

Ideally, the ActiveMQ project would publish a jakarta-bound alternate client. Am I doing something obviously stupid here?

Comment: Right now, I'm trying to get feedback from the ActiveMQ project itself: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-7309

Comment: I updated my answer to add details regarding AMQ-7309. For what it's worth, I'm an ActiveMQ developer although I'm mainly focused on ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: You're, of course, correct. :)

Luckily, in the other thread, I was made aware that I was wrong about ActiveMQ holding me back from Java 17, so the migration to Java 17 is complete while EE9+ has to wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveMQ Classic doesn't ship a Jakarta Messaging 3 compatible client (i.e. the first version of Jakarta Messaging to use the `jakarta` namespace). There is some discussion on [AMQ-7309](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-7309) regarding this, but it is still in the "open" state which means there is no Jakarta Messaging 3 compatible client for ActiveMQ Classic at this point. There *may* be one in the future, but it would come with the 5.18.0 release at the earliest and that release currently isn't scheduled.

ActiveMQ Artemis *does* ship a Jakarta Messaging 3 compatible client, but it can't be used to connect to ActiveMQ Classic because it doesn't speak the OpenWire protocol.

You're not doing something obviously stupid. What you want to do just isn't currently supported directly by ActiveMQ Classic.

However, you could use [Qpid JMS 2.0.0](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-2.0.0/index.html) which supports Jakarta Messaging 3 via the AMQP 1.0 protocol. I'm not sure all the features will work since ActiveMQ Classic doesn't fully support JMS 2, but it's your best option.

Comment: Jakarta JMS compatible version ActiveMQ 5.18.0 released [ANN] Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.0 has been released.

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.18 _has_ been released, but it only provides a pseudo Jakarta Messaging 3.1 implementation. It still doesn't support async send with a `CompletionListener`, sending messages with a delivery delay, and using shared topic consumers which are arguably the most important new features originally introduced in JMS 2. However, if you're using JMS 1.1 API calls with the `jakarta` namespace then it should work fine.

Comment: @JustinBertram i'm trying to use activemq-client-jakarta and all work almost fine, i can't create JmsTemplate with a pooledconnectionfactory because activemq-jms-pool doesn't have migrate to jakarta namespace. Does exist a solution for this? thanks

Comment: @MançauxPierre-Alexandre I'd recommend you use [pooled-jms](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms). It was forked from ActiveMQ's pool and support for Jakarta Messaging was added in 3.0. The latest release is [3.1](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.messaginghub/pooled-jms/3.1.0).

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks for your reactivity, i have integrate pooled-jms and all work as expected ;)

Comment: Fantastic! My client application is now able to move into the Jakarta namepace and "beyond".

Comment: Unfortunately, my unit tests that were using the 'activemq-broker' artifact still depend on javax.jms. I attempted to replace this with artemis-junit-5 using the OpenWire protocol but there seems be no Jakarta compatible 'artemis-jakarta-junit-5' artifact. Until that becomes available, it seems I will still be stuck at EE8.

Comment: @JustinBertram another question about this problem, i m using tcp and https connection in my application so i need to use activemq-http but no project activemq-http-jakarta exist, did you know if its planned? i see that activemq-client-jakarta is just succession of maven plugin to create jakarta one, perhaps same things can be done for http jar? thanks

Comment: @MançauxPierre-Alexandre, you should ask a new question about this.

Comment: @JustinBertram ok, done.