# ActiveMQ 5.17.0 and Spring JMS 6.0.4 is not working

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am trying to migrate the spring-jms 5.3.23 to 6.0.4 version. Spring JMS is now using the Jakarta Messaging API, and that is not working with ActiveMQ 5.17.0 libraries. I couldn't find latest ActiveMQ libraries to work for Spring JMS 6.0.4.

I couldn't find a solution to use ActiveMQ and Spring JMS 6.0.4 to send and receive JMS messages.

Comment: Spring 6 moved to the jakarta namespace. See the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457580/how-can-i-move-to-the-jakarta-namespace-while-using-amazon-mq

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ "Classic" doesn't ship a Jakarta Messaging 3 compatible client (i.e. the first version of Jakarta Messaging to use the `jakarta` namespace). There is some discussion on [AMQ-7309](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-7309) regarding this, but it is still in the "open" state which means there is no official Jakarta Messaging 3 compatible client for ActiveMQ "Classic" at this point. There are plans to provide one in the future, but before transitioning to the `jakarta` namespace JMS 2 support must be implemented. These changes look to be coming with the 5.18.0 release at the earliest and that release currently isn't scheduled. You can specifically track progress with the JMS 2 implementation [here](https://activemq.apache.org/jms2).

To be clear, [ActiveMQ **Artemis**](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) has full support for JMS 2 and provides a [Jakarta-compatible client](https://search.maven.org/search?q=artemis-jakarta-client). You may consider migrating as once Artemis reaches a sufficient level of feature parity with the "Classic" code-base it will become the next major version of ActiveMQ.