# Test code using ActiveMQ BrokerService breaks after upgrading Spring Boot from 2.7.x to 3.0.3

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis, spring-messaging

My project currently has test code that connects to an ActiveMQ broker configured as follows:

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;

@Slf4j
public class MqTestConfiguration {

  public static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";

  public static BrokerService getBrokerServiceInstance() throws Exception {
    BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
    brokerService.setUseJmx(false);
    brokerService.setPersistent(false);
    brokerService.addConnector(BROKER_URL);
    return brokerService;
  }
}
```

After upgrading Spring Boot from `2.7.x` to `3.0.3`, the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq` dependency no longer resolves since according to the [Spring Boot 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#other-removals), support for Apache ActiveMQ "Classic" has been removed. Thus, this code fails to compile.

What is the recommendation for this type of code? I've noticed on Maven Central that `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:2.7.9` was recently released but that no `3.0.x` releases exist. Does this mean that going forward, Spring won't provide any starter support for ActiveMQ "Classic" on the `3.0.x` line? Is the recommendation to migrate this code to use ActiveMQ Artemis instead after migrating to Spring Boot `3.0.x`? I have seen that ActiveMQ Artemis is discussed in the latest [Spring Boot Messaging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.jms.artemis) documentation, so I'm just trying to get a sense of where the project support and direction is headed. If so, is there a guide that discusses how to migrate this type of code to ActiveMQ Artemis? I appreciate any guidance here that anyone can provide.

Comment: It's not a question of "Spring won't provide...", it's that "ActiveMQ won't provide a client" - see the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457580/how-can-i-move-to-the-jakarta-namespace-while-using-amazon-mq so, yes, Artemis is the way forward.

Comment: Jakarta JMS compatible version ActiveMQ 5.18.0 released [ANN] Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.0 has been released!